# How to get run status of Scenarios in AfterScenario JBehave

Tags: java, junit4, jbehave, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I am trying to get the status of Scenarios (ie. Failed, Skipped or Passed) in AfterScenario method in Jbehave using junit. I want it to use this to genrate Extent Reports.

Comment: we can create Extent Reports with jbehave. we need to create costumed reporter class which either implements StoryReporter or extends NullStoryReporter class and override methods to define ExtentReport functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Extent Reports tracks its own scenario statistics based upon the scenario steps reported.

While Extent Reports does not directly support JBehave like it does Cucumber, there's excellent documentation on the site as to how to implement BDD-style reporting directly.

I've written my own class implementing an extent report object that reports stories as features, and processes scenarios and steps.

And pass/fail/skip on the step level will be reported both on the step level as well as the scenario level on the report.

Comment: Can you share any relevant link or code that can help understand concept.